# How can I report an Azure startup failure to user

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012

My company produces a tool that the user installs on the server prior to publishing their project. For Azure deployment we have a startup script (a simple .cmd file) that installs our tool. It has the recommended checks for repeat runs, and logs everything. The problem is that the user can't tell if there was an installation problem without RDPing to the role instance and checking the logs.

My question is: if there is a failure installing our tool is there any way to report it back to Visual Studio?

Comment: If there is a failure presumably it will be reported in the logs. So getting the logs elsewhere so you can do something with them seems like the challenge. Perhaps you could add a second startup task that would FTP the logs elsewhere, or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is.  If I recall correctly, the startup tasks are fired off as part of the role's startup process (depending on the startup task type - simple, background, etc.).  That script is running along with other things like the plug-in that configures Remote Desktop (which I believe the plug-in is a specially packaged type of startup script).  I don't think there is anyway to report back (to whatever initiated the deployment operation) what startup tasks failed.

Comment: Bummer. It's what I expected but I hoped there was a way to do it.